# vmware fusion add .tfignore file or download from tfsonline not working

Tags: macos, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, vmware-fusion

Situation is as follows

- running windows 10 with vs2015 on my mac with Fusion
- added share in fusion so I can use my TFS folder on my Mac and in my Fusion vm (for xamarin studio and such)

Problem

- Adding a .tfignore file isn't possible
- Adding it through tfsonline leads to not being able to get the file from tfsonline

Seems to me it's a problem with accessing dot file and sharing them via a vmware host share: access denied

Bright ideas anyone?

Comment: How did you create the shared folder? What is the behavior and is there any error message when you get the created tfignore file from tfsonline?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .tfignore file from VS automatically via following steps:

1. Open “Pending Changes” from Team Explorer.
2. Click “Detect: xxx” link under “Excluded Changes”. (If there is no “Detected: xxx” link under “Exclude Changes”, create a text file in your workspace to get the link appeared)
3. Select a file and right click on it.
4. Choose “Ignore this location item”, “Ignore by extension”, “Ignore by file name” or “Ignore by folder” option.
5. A .tfignore file will be created in your local workspace and appears in “Pending Changes\Include Changes”.

Then you can open this file and edit it to meet your requirement.